# PyQGIS Standalone QVectorLayer works and QRasterLayer not work without QgsApplication / initQgis()

Tags: python, raster, pyqgis, standalone, qgsvectorlayer

I'm trying to make a standalone python app and I want to use in some parts of app functions of PyQGIS.

I'm testing things to understand how it works.

Doing tests I have found a situation that I do not understand.

I can load a `QgsVectorLayer` without `QgsApplication.initQgis()`, but with `QgsRasterLayer` this not works.

Can someone explain why this happends? (I know it is recommended to start always with `QgsApplication.initQgis()`.

Here is my test code.

Works `QgsVectorLayer` but not `QgsRasterLayer`.

```
from qgis.core import QgsVectorLayer,QgsRasterLayer

file='MyTrack.gpx'+"|layername=track_points"
vlayer = QgsVectorLayer(file, "Termes", "ogr")
if vlayer.isValid():
    print('Load Correct QgsVectorLayer')
else:
    print('Not Load QgsVectorLayer')

for feature in vlayer.getFeatures():
    print(feature.geometry().asWkt())
    break

uri="dpiMode=7&identifier=mdt:Elevacion4258_25&url=http://www.ign.es/wcs/mdt"

DEM  = QgsRasterLayer(uri, 'my wcs layer', 'wcs')              
if not DEM.isValid():
    print("QgsRasterLayer failed to load! ")
else:
    print("QgsRasterLayer Load Correct!")
```

Works `QgsVectorLayer` and `QgsRasterLayer` (take about 1 minute to load)

```
from qgis.core import QgsApplication
qgs = QgsApplication([], False)
qgs.initQgis()

from qgis.core import QgsVectorLayer,QgsRasterLayer

file='MyTrack.gpx'+"|layername=track_points"
vlayer = QgsVectorLayer(file, "Termes", "ogr")
if vlayer.isValid():
    print('Load Correct QgsVectorLayer')
else:
    print('Not Load QgsVectorLayer')

for feature in vlayer.getFeatures():
    print(feature.geometry().asWkt())
    break

uri="dpiMode=7&identifier=mdt:Elevacion4258_25&url=http://www.ign.es/wcs/mdt"

DEM  = QgsRasterLayer(uri, 'my wcs layer', 'wcs')              
if not DEM.isValid():
    print("QgsRasterLayer failed to load! ")
else:
    print("QgsRasterLayer Load Correct!")
```